# form_tag No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a custom method buy inside order controller

I've declared a special route with the following: which is sell_order_path

```
resources :orders do
  post 'buy', on: :member
end
```

And here's my form tag

```
<%= form_tag(buy_order_path(@symbol)) do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :stock_price, '55' %>
<%= label_tag :stock_quantity, 'Buy Quantity' %>
<%= text_field_tag :stock_quantity, params[:stock_quantity] %> 
<%= submit_tag "Buy", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I clicked submit, it says No route matches [POST] "/orders/CC3.SI/buy"

It work when I used

```
<%= form_tag(buy_order_path('5')) do %>
```

However, I would need a dynamic. Any idea how? I have a feeling that it how I created the route.

By the way @symbol is just a variable right now, not an object

Comment: You have `sell_order_path` defined and are using `buy_order_path`!

Comment: Sorry about the sell_order_path, edited to buy_order path. However this doesn't solve the issue

Comment: How is @symbol being populated?

Comment: it is populated by the order controller, which call a model that call a restful service to obtain the symbol value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did

## **Instead of**

```
resource :order do
  post :buy, on: :member
end
```

which will generate a route of

```
/orders/:id/buy(.:format)
```

## **I changed my route to**

```
resource :order do
  post :buy, on: :collection
end
```

which will generate a route of

```
/orders/buy(.:format)
```

Following on, I insert the symbol parameter into my form_tag

```
<%= form_tag(buy_order_path()) do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :symbol, @symbol %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :stock_price, '55' %>
<%= label_tag :stock_quantity, 'Buy Quantity' %>
<%= text_field_tag :stock_quantity, params[:stock_quantity] %> 
<%= submit_tag "Buy", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

**The above work**, however I am not sure if this is the best way as user might be able to see the hidden field tag and edit the html value. Is there a better way for to pass value to controller?